# Run StyleCop against iis based Web Project on buildserver

Tags: iis, stylecop

How do I run stylecop against an iis based webproject on a buildserver?
Buildserver runs in continuous integration and I would like this automated.

With a library I can add a few lines to the .csproj and its done. I believe it to be a website application project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with the project type, projects need to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a web application project or a web site in Visual Studio? With the former option, it is compiled into an assembly, so you could always run StyleCop from the build scripts when building the assembly.

Alternatively you could run StyleCop as a plugin from within VisualStudio, but you're probably asking for automation here. It all depends on your build process, I think. There are various build configurations, so please elaborate a bit more on what are you actually doing on this build server. Continuous integration?

Comment: Yes, continuous integration & it is automation I'm after. With a library I can add a few lines to the .csproj and its done. 

I believe it to be a website application project.